# CSS3 Animation Works in Safari 9 Locally, but Not Live

Tags: css, animation, safari, webkit

I'm building a novelty wedding announcement microsite that combines a dynamic background image populated by an Instagram feed with two different CSS3 animations on top. The first animation features the bobblehead couple zooming AWAY while the second animation is composed of scrolling text that rolls slowly into view on an angled plane, Star Wars style.

Basically, everything seems to be working except for the scrolling text which is not visible, although it does appear to be animating, but is simply hidden behind the background image.

Its works fine in Chrome and when I view it locally is Safari, just not live. I'm sure it's something simple. Any insight into this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!!!

[Here's a link to the live site.](http://ericandjohncelebrate.com)

CSS

```
#bobblehead {
    margin: auto 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 800px;
    float: middle;
    -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 13s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 13s;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    0%   {width: 800px; height: 1300px}
    100% {width:0px; height: 0px;}
}


#titles
{
    position: fixed;
    width: 18em;
    height: 50em;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -9em;
    font-size: 700%;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: justify;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: yellow;
    z-index: 100000;


    transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    transform: perspective(300px) rotateX(25deg);

    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(300px) rotateX(25deg);
}

#titles:after
{
    position: absolute;
    content: ' ';
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 60%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, transparent 100%);
    pointer-events: none;
}

#titlecontent
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    animation-delay: none;
    -webkit-animation-name: scroll;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 450s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinte;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-delay: none;
}

@keyframes scroll {
    0% { top: 100%; }
    100% { top: -170%; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes scroll {
    0% { top: 100%; }
    100% { top: -170%; }
}
```